# Compare 'YYYYMM' to two columns with differents data type Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm using Teradata SQL Assistant, and I have an SQL issue similar to this one below.

Table_a (contains more than 500 million rows):

```
 id|    b     | c   |d
  1|2021-05-03|2 020|  6
  2|2019-04-22|2 019|  4
  3|2018-11-15|2 018| 10
```

In my query I  want to select only the rows where year/month of b is equal or greater than c/d, so in this example i will get only the row id = 2.

The problem here is that the column c is a **smallint**, d is **byteint**, and b is a **date**. I did not find a way to do `to_char(b,'yyyymm')` with `c||d` because c and d contains spaces and c column may have only one number (for example 6 and not 06 if the month is between January and September), so I did this:

```
select * from table_a
where cast(extract(year from b) as smallint) > c
or (  cast(extract(year from b) as smallint) = c and cast(extract(month from b) as byteint) >= d)
```

My query takes so much time and sometimes it fails with no more spool space (even if I put sample 10 for example). I guess the problem is in the data type and in the converting. I already tested it without converting, but I got the same performance issue.

Comment: Your current approach is more efficient than casting three columns to char. Regarding spool there are probably too many rows in your result, you might try asking your DBA for more spool :-) SAMPLE will not help because it creates *all* matching rows before the sample step (TOP might work).

Comment: thank you @dnoeth, you think if i do not cast(extract(year or month from b) as smalint/byteint) and let just the extract = c/d is more efficient ( i think extract return integer so no need to cast it again) ?

Comment: Extract returns integer, there's no need to cast to byte or smallint.